# Is it normal to have different results pattern if data sort is different but the covariances are the same when doing propensity score matching in R?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, propensity-scores

Is it normal to have different results pattern if data sort is different but the covariances are the same when calculating with propensity score matching in R?

There is data with sample size of about 100.

If I calculate for P-value of the operation time from the data sorted by the operated day, there is no significant difference.

However, it shows significant difference if the imported data is sorted by the operation time descending even though the propensity score is calculated with the same covariances.

Why? and what should be the correct way?
It seems you can manipulate the result by sorting the target item descending even though calculating with the exact same data and the exact same procedure.

Comment: I think you mean "covariates" (i.e., variables to adjust for) rather than "covariances" (i.e., the correlation between two variables).

Comment: @Noah Thanks for correction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use nearest neighbor matching, the result is sensitive to the order of the matches. The relationship between the order of matches and match quality has been studied in the literature, but the results only apply in general and may not apply to your specific dataset. You should see matching order as one of many tuning parameters that can be adjusted in matching. The best matching order is the one that yields the best balance.

You can simply avoid making this choice by using optimal matching, which is deterministic and doesn't depend on order. Optimal matching minimizes the overall within-pair distances between units. With larger samples, optimal matching may be slow or intractable, so nearest neighbor matching can be a fast alternative. Otherwise, optimal matching should be preferred when possible.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm using nearest neighbor within caliper matching(Caliper width=0.2). I'd say that nearest neighbor matching without caliper would bring the wider range of different result patterns. Do you think that Optimal matching provide less different result pattern when compared to Greedy matching(Nearest neighbor within caliper)?

Comment: Did you try matching without a caliper and decide that a caliper was needed to achieve balance, or did you just decide to use a caliper from the start? If you can get good balance without a caliper, then there isn't a large benefit to using one. The question of which method to prefer depends on which method yields the best balance while preserving the size of the remaining sample and ensuring generalizability to the correct target population. Use those metrics to decide how to select a match. This is described in the `MatchIt` vignettes.